# JOIN condition in PIG Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

### SQL

```
SELECT m.x,m.y,n.a,n.b
from mydata1 m,mydata2 n
WHERE m.x=n.a
AND  m.y>= n.y
```

### PIG

```
A = LOAD 'mydata1' AS (x: int, y: datetime);
B = LOAD 'mydata2' AS (a: int, b: datetime);
```

I now need to join both the tables using the above sql condition.
How will I implement the above logic in PIG using the join condition?

Comment: As this is not possible try with [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/udf.html)

Comment: try ´CROSS´ in conjunction with ´FILTER´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
A = LOAD 'mydata1' AS (x: int, y: datetime);  
B = LOAD 'mydata2' AS (a: int, b: datetime); 
C = JOIN A BY x, B BY a;
D = FILTER C BY ToUnixTime(y) >= ToUnixTime(b);
DUMP D;
```